# How do I access "wp-content/plugins" after being locked out due to installing the Visual Composer plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ftp

I'm using `Elementor builder` and `OceanWP` theme. Immediately after installing the `Visual Composer` plugin, I immediately received the following error. I receive this error each time I attempt to access the admin dashboard. How do I disable plugins outside of the dashboard?

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function vc_map() in
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-content/plugins/weeby-testimonial/add-ons/testimony-addons.php:32
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   WEEBY_testimonial_class->push_js_option('') #1
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-settings.php(505): do_action('init') #4
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-config.php(90):
>   require_once('/home/gataling/...') #5
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('/home/gataling/...') #6
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34):
>   require_once('/home/gataling/...') #7
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10):
>   require_once('/home/gataling/...') #8 {main} thrown in
>   /home/gataling/public_html/wp-content/plugins/weeby-testimonial/add-ons/testimony-addons.php
>   on line 32"

I can't login to my `wp-admin` to uninstall the plugin. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

1.Easiest way: You can access your server via FTP and rename the folder of the plugin that causes the error.

The error states that not Elementor is causing the error but a plugin called "Weeby testimonial", be aware of that.

Once you've done that, wordpress won't be able to load the plugin and the error is gone.

2. Advanced: You can disable the plugin by modifying the database. Within your wp_options table search for option_name `active_plugins` and remove the content. But careful: This will disable ALL active plugins.

Comment: Thanks! I've been attempting to access my server via FTP using FileZilla, but am having issues setting up a server. I downloaded and xml file from Siteground (my hosting service) but I'm not entirely sure what my next move is. How do I set up FileZilla so that I can access my website's FTP files?

Comment: Usually your hoster provides some instructions on how to access your server via FTP. You will need at least an IP-Adress (Host), Username and Password to be able to connect via FTP.

Take a look at this page: (https://www.siteground.com/kb/establish-ftp-connection-hosting-account/)

Comment: I got it figured out. Thank you so much!